# Co-ordinate Geometry - Circles & Parabola

Tags: calculus, circles, conic-sections

A circle with centre at $(15,-3)$ is tangent to $3y=x^2$ at a point in the first quadrant. What is the radius of the circle?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Let the equation of the circle be $(x-15)^2 + (y+3)^2 = r^2$. The derivative is

$$\begin{align*}
2(x-15) + 2(y+3)\frac{dy}{dx} &= 0\\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= -\frac{x-15}{y+3}
\end{align*}$$

The derivative of the parabola is

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2x}3$$

Equating the two derivatives give

$$\begin{align*}
-\frac{x-15}{y+3} &= \frac{2x}3\\
-3(x-15) &= 2x(y+3)\\
-3x+45 &= 2xy+6x\\
y &= \frac{45-9x}{2x}
\end{align*}$$

Substitute $y$ into the parabola $3y= x^2$, (because the tangent point must be on the parabola,)

$$\begin{align*}
3\cdot\frac{45-9x}{2x} &= x^2\\
135 - 27x &= 2x^3\\
2x^3+27x - 135 &= 0\\
(x-3)(2x^2+6x + 45) &= 0\\
x &= 3\\
y &= 3\\
r &= \sqrt{(3-15)^2 + (3+3)^2}\\
&= 6\sqrt 5
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the tangent point is the minimizer of the function $(x,y) \mapsto (x-15)^{2}+(y+3)^{2}$ restricted on the set $\{ (x,y) \mid y = x^{2}/3 \}$. So the problem reduces to minimize the function $x \mapsto (x-15)^{2} + (x^{2}/3 + 3)^{2}$. Could you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

If the curves are tangent then the slopes are equal at the point of tangency.

Use the derivative to find the slopes of the tangents of both curves.

find $x,y$ such that the tangents are equal.

$(x+3)^2 + (y-15)^2 = r^2\\
2(x+3) + 2(y-15)\frac {dy}{dx} = 0\\
\frac {dy}{dx} = -\frac {x+3}{y-15}$

$3y =x^2\\
\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac 23 x$

Between:

$-\frac {x+3}{y-15} = \frac 23 x\\
3y =x^2$

There is enough information to solve your problem.